# Remove white flicker after Splashscreen PhoneGap

Tags: android, cordova, splash-screen

I'm trying to remove the white flicker from PhoneGap 2.9.0.

First of all can somebody clarify me a few things?

- For PhoneGap 2.9.0, if I use local build (Eclipse) is the config.xml used or is it just for PhoneGap build? If so, how can I use instructions that were written in config.xml if it is not used.
- Is AndroidManifest.xml actually the config.xml file (for local build)?

I managed to create a Splash screen and I put it in drawable folders, but the problem is that each time after the Splashscreen a white flicker is displayed.

How can I remove this white flicker?

I saw many workarounds, but they didn't worked. Actually I did't understand much of them because some were in local build some in PhoneGap build.

Comment: So is there anyone who knows and can clarify not just for me, for all users who have this king of issue?

Comment: I reallly don't get the useness of this site because nobody never answers anything I ask...Sorry

Comment: Your first question wasn't really a question, the reason why it was closed, and this one was posted 5 hours ago on a relatively small topic for this site, it only has 14 views for example. You just need to give it some time for people to respond and provide more information. Have you read the documentation for both PhoneGap and the Build service? It is pretty thorough and covers your first couple questions. And what have you tried to remove it? What were the workarounds?

Comment: Sorry for that.. I also posted a question 2 days ago and nobody has answered it thats why I was so "frustrated". I read the documentation but as said before its very poor and doesn't offer enough information for beginners, not just for me, in general as I saw several posts about the poor documentation and I thought somebody with more experience could share some of his workareounds. I tried everything and I managed to get rid of it by making the ui-overlay-a backgroung black as I wish to use a black fadeout in my application when chenging screens.

Comment: But now I have another problem. The black screen that is supposed to fade out by each page is fading but the images from the application screen except the one from the footer are on top of it and they disappear instantly without the black effect. The image from header and the dext from that page are working properly... Any clue about it?

Comment: Can you post some of your code? Are you using jQuery Mobile or any other UI Framework?

Comment: I'm using jquerry mobile and phonegap.

Comment: Have you tried any of the solutions from this site? Like this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9975372/white-flash-between-pages-with-phonegap-and-jquery-mobile-for-mobile-app

Comment: I tryed with background-color: black !important; and its working halfway. For the fade transition it works but the transition still happedns in back of the 2 pictures. For the pop transition it works well exept the fact that after each transition the whole page moves down with 1 pixel... I can't figure it out why... I tryed making the body absolte and width 100% but without success... Do you have other  suggestions? Tanks